# How can I open a file in its default application from the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, uti

How can I open a file in its default application from the command line?

For example if I have a file `foo.doc`, can I type `command ./foo.doc` into the CLI and have that file open in Word?

Note: on my linux machine, I would use `xdg-open` but that doesn't work on my Mac.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use:

```
open foo.doc
```

or, alternatively:

```
open -n foo.doc
```

to force it to open a new instance if one is already open for that app.

Comment: `open -n` opens a new instance, not a window.

Comment: Also nice is `open .` (or any directory name in place of `.`), which opens Finder (the default application for a directory).